# Error with Mongo Client

Tags: c#, mongodb, debian

When I try to connected to a Mongo server with the mongo client, I get the following warning:

```
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: no such cmd
```

It still gives me access and I can access the database.
The issue is when I try accessing the DB from C#. That warning throws an exception, and the application terminates.

The mongod command used was

```
mongod --port 30000
```

No startup scripts as far as I can tell.

The mongo server is running on Debian, on another machine.

Update

The error thrown by .NET is

```
Unable to connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:30000: Command 'ping' failed: no such cmd (response: { "errmsg" : "no such cmd", "bad cmd" : { "ping" : 1 }, "ok" : 0.0 }).
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The server version was older than the client version.